# How to solve 2 ÷ 2 ÷ 2 ? ${}{}{}{}$

Tags: problem-solving, arithmetic

$$2 ÷ 2 ÷ 2 = (2 ÷ 2) ÷ 2 \ \ \text{OR}\ \ 2 ÷ (2 ÷ 2) ?$$

Is there any standard rule which is world wide accepted for solving this type of expressions? If I process the expression from left to right then I will get $\dfrac12$. But if I process it from right to left then I get $\dfrac21$, that is $2$.

It might be that it is in invalid expression. But these type of questions are usualy asked in India's exams. E.g. the 82$^{th}$ question of SBI Clerk Exam (Held on 06-07-2008) was:
$$82.Q:\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 14400÷64÷9=?$$
The answer given  was $25$. They appear to assume the order of execution from left to right.

> So is the standard rule is to execute the order of operations is from left to right?

Comment: If such a question is given, I would solve it from left to right.  That said, such questions are obviously not written by mathematicians.

Comment: I agree with Carl but people who write things like that are probably sadistic but surely not mathematicians !

Comment: Most calculators and computer languages will execute multiplication and division left-to-right. Similarly for addition and subtraction. But for other expressions such as `1+2*3` and `2^3^2`, answers vary between implementations: so either `9` or `7` and either `64` or `512`, and most mathematicians would choose $1+2\times 3= 7$ and $2^{3^2}=512$, in the former case doing multiplication before addition, and in the latter case operating right-to-left for exponentiation.

Comment: I see it as $\frac{a}{b/c}=\frac{ac}{b}$, +1 for letting others know what "type"(insert your fav. word here) of questions are asked in India and I totally agree with Carl and Claude

Comment: @Henry: Could you point out an "implementation" that calculates 1+2*3 = 9? I would be most curious to find out which computer language / compiler (interpreter) combo you had in mind when making your point!!

Comment: @gnometorule: as a example, the Windows calculator calc.exe does both: it gives $9$ when in "standard" form and $7$ when in "scientific" form

Answer (score 1):

$$2 ÷ 2 ÷ 2 = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} $$

Also in multiplication and division you have to go left to right then if you have addition and substraction you also have to go from left to right.
Also if you have exponentiation you do that first and if you have brackets you have to do what is inside the brackets, before everything else.

Howewer when you have function composition, and exponentiation you go from right to left. For example:

$$f \circ g  |_{x} = f(g(x))$$ 
so you first apply $g$ to $x$ and then you apply $f$ to the result of $g(x)$.
When you have exponentiation:
$$a^b = a \uparrow b$$
$$a^{b^c} =  a \uparrow b \uparrow c$$ 
In the last case you also go from right to left. 
So:
$$\left(a^b\right)^c\neq a^{(b^c)}$$

Comment: How $2 ÷ 2 ÷ 2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yeah that is wrong, I corrected it.

Comment: @05storm26,  OP has asked a simple arithmetical problem, can you add something to the discussion under consideration?

Comment: @Vikram I understand what "o5strom26" is trying to say. In many cases the order is from right to left as he is saying. But $2 ÷ 2 ÷ 2 = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ is still wrong :-/ . Nonetheless '+1'.

Comment: I agree, I think the answer is $1/2.$